# How symbols equal each others?

Tags: ruby, arrays, symbols

When I do `:symbol == :symbol` I find that its true. They are the same.

If this is the case, how can we create arrays like this:

```
a = [{:name=>"Michael"},{:name=>"John"}]
```

Comment: Why do you think this shouldn't be possible?

Comment: There's no contradiction there. The elements in `a` are distinct, and moreover arrays can contain duplicate elements. You may be thinking of a hash, in which case keys must be unique, and you would indeed not find two occurrences of `:symbol` in the set of keys.

Comment: @DouglasFShearer It just confuses me as the first :name is the same as the second :name in the other hash

Comment: The key is the same, but each hash is different. What you would not see is two or more instance of the same symbol as keys in a hash: `people = {name: 'Joe', name: 'Jane', name: 'Sally'}`. To build some intuition for why that would be illegal, think about what `people[:name]` should produce. Similarly, `a[0]` and `a[1]` pose no such conceptual difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look the below code :

```
a = [{:name=>"Michael"},{:name=>"John"}]
a.map(&:object_id) # => [70992070, 70992050]
```

This is because `a` is an array of Hash, but they are 2 different hash objects. In Ruby, `Hash` must have *uniq* key. But 2 different hash can have same named symbols as keys.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about hash keys. One hash cannot contain the same key twice, but two different hashes can have the same object as a key. For example:

```
a_key = "hello"
spanish = { a_key => "hola" }
french = { a_key => "bonjour" }
some_array = [spanish, french]
```

On top of that, it is possible for arrays to contain duplicate objects (e.g. `[1, 2, 1]` is valid) -- but these aren't even duplicates. Two hashes that contain the same key are still different objects.

There's nothing at all unusual about an array like that. In fact, it's normal for hashes in an array to have keys in common, because usually if you want to put things in an array, it means they have something in common that you can use to deal with them in the same way.